# Ctrl+c is not working in GUI mode of Installer

Tags: install4j

Hi we are working on GUI+CLI based installer for CentOS 7 platform.
If we hit ctrl+c on terminal while execution of installer in CLI mode the cancelled event is fired and we have called custom rollback script which gets executed properly.
If we hit ctrl+c on terminal while execution of installer in GUI mode the cancelled event is not fired and it fails to execute the rollback script.

Why there is difference in behavior for GUI and CLI mode?
Is there is any way where we can disable ctrl+z ctrl+c ctrl+d while execution?

Answer (score 1):

As of install4j 9.0.1, the CTRL-C is indeed not caught and processed by the GUI installer. I have added this feature request to the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks Ingo!
Just wanted to know that does Install4j supports Windows Subsystem For Linux ?Like the installer created will work on WSL based linux?

Comment: Yes, the Unix installers will work in WSL.